# Spliting a file into multiple files based on common line prefix

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a file with the following format.

```
prefix1: line 1
prefix1: line 2
prefix1: line 3
prefix2: line 4

prefix2: line 5
prefix3: line 6

prefix3: line 7
prefix3: line 8
prefix3: line 9
prefix3: line 10
```

I would like to split this into three files with names `prefix1`, `prefix2`, `prefix3`, with the newlines intact as part of whichever file either entirely contains them.

**In the real file, there might be `n` prefixes and not just 3.**

I could write a python script to implement the functionality directly, but I wonder if there's a shorter way to do it in `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one-liner works for the job:

```
 awk -F: '{f=$1?$1:f; print > f}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat file
prefix1: line 1
prefix1: line 2
prefix1: line 3
prefix2: line 4

prefix2: line 5
prefix3: line 6

prefix3: line 7
prefix3: line 8
prefix3: line 9
prefix3: line 10

kent$  awk -F: '{f=$1?$1:f; print > f}' file

kent$  head prefix*
==> prefix1 <==
prefix1: line 1
prefix1: line 2
prefix1: line 3

==> prefix2 <==
prefix2: line 4

prefix2: line 5

==> prefix3 <==
prefix3: line 6

prefix3: line 7
prefix3: line 8
prefix3: line 9
prefix3: line 10
```

you mentioned **n** prefixes. if N is large enough, the above awk line could fail with something like "opened too many files". to solve it, we could close file after write/append text into it.

that is , the line could be :

```
awk -F: '{f=$1?$1:f; print >> f; close(f)}' file
```

this line works no matter your input file is sorted by prefix or not.